Cartan-Eilenberg SSeq collapsing at the E2 -page to the Adams SSeq (Ravenel's green book Theorem 4.4.3)
I have a question related to Theorem 4.4.3 in Ravenel's green book about Cartan-Eilenberg SSeq (CESS) collapsing at the $E_2$-page to the Adams SSeq. Before stating the question, let me state the results and context.
Recall, that the dual Steenrod algebra $A_*$ is
\begin{equation}
A_*=
\begin{cases}
P(\xi_1,\xi_2,...) \text{ with }|\xi_i|=2^{i}-1\text{ for }p=2 \\
E(\tau_0,\tau_1,...)\otimes P(\xi_1,\xi_2,...) \text{ with } |\tau|=2p^i-1 \text{ and }|\xi_i|=2p^i-2 \text{ for }p>2 
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
We consider a Hopf algebra map
\begin{equation}
\phi:P(\xi_1,\xi_2,...)\rightarrow A_*
\end{equation}
where for $p=2$, we take $\xi_i\mapsto \xi_i^2$, and for $p>2$, we just take the inclusion map. The corresponding cokernel, can be described as $E_*=A_*\otimes_{P(\xi_1,...)}\mathbb{F}_p$, and is isomorphic to $E(\xi_1,\xi_2,...)$ for $p=2$, and $E(\tau_0,\tau_1,...)$ for $p>2$.
This means that we have an extension of Hopf algebras $A_*\overset{\phi}{\rightarrow} A_*\rightarrow E_*$ and so we have a Cartan-Eilenberg spectral sequence converging to $Ext_{A_*}(\mathbb{F}_p,\mathbb{F}_p)$ with $E_2$-page, described as
\begin{equation}
Ext_{A_*}(\mathbb{F}_p,Ext_{E_*}(\mathbb{F}_p,\mathbb{F}_p))
\end{equation}
Now, we know that $Ext_{E_*}(\mathbb{F}_p,\mathbb{F}_p)=P(h_{10},h_{20},...)$, where the notation of the generators is imported from the May SSeq. And similarly, we also have a $A_*$-coaction on the polynomial ring given by
\begin{equation}
\psi(h_{n0})=\sum_{i=0}^{n} \xi_{n-i}^{p^{i}}\otimes h_{i0}
\end{equation}
Here is the claim that I don't understand. `For $p>2$ the CESS collapses from $E_2$-page with no nontrivial extension'. However, I think that in the formulation I stated it, this should be true also for p=2.
The proof in the book is for $p>2$ and is based on giving an additional grading on Ext induced from $P(h_{10},...)$ and deducing that the differentials must respect this grading.

Why do you think it collapses when $p=2$?
